# Layout issues with spans and Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

TB3 here. Here is the respective [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oh69hq71/15/). I am trying to build a little **minitron** (mini jumbotron) that has the following layout:

[image]

As you can see, there is a main `<div>` given the `minitron` class. Each 'minitron' has:

- An icon (Glyphicon)
- A name
- A description
- A 'Learn More' button

Unfortunately my CSS-fu is pretty weak, and as you can see in that fiddle, I'm just not achieving the desired layout.

Here's my attempt at some CSS rules:

```
.minitron-icon {
    width:20%;
    height: 20%;
    margin: 5px;
}
.minitron-name {
    font-size: 18px;
}
.minitron-desc {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 5px;
}
.minitron-learnmore {
    width: 95%;
}
```

Can anyone spot where I'm going awry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this one? https://jsfiddle.net/oh69hq71/17/

Taking advantage of BS grid system using rows and columns. The first row containing the glyphicon and name/description, the other one with the learn more full width.

```
    <div class="well minitron">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-2">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-piggy-bank minitron-icon"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-10">
        <div class="row">
          <span class="minitron-name">Some Name</span>
        </div>
      <div class="row">
        <span class="minitron-desc">A short meaningful description goes here.</span>
      </div>
  </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <button class="minitron-learnmore btn btn-success" type="button">LEARN MORE ABOUT JUPITER!</button>
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

***Update:**

- Increasing glyphicon size: In the glyphicon span set its style as "font-size:1.5em;"
- To align it closer to name and description, add the style="text-align:right" at the glyphicon div container
- The description is aligned to the named without the original css styles.
- To increase padding (or margin) between the learn more button and description/icon, increase the learn more div top margin

New fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/oh69hq71/18/

Comment: Thanks @marcanuy (+1) - I think we're closer! A few items that are still falling a wee bit short of what I'm hoping to accomplish: (1) the glyphicon (piggy bank) is way to small. If you look at my drawing of the intended layout, I'm hoping to get the glyphicon to be significantly larger and to make it right next to the name/description sections (with a little padding in between). (2) The description appear to be a little indented in from the name - I'm hoping to make them left-aligned with each other. Last, (3) I'm looking for some padding between the description and the 'Learn More' button.

Comment: Thanks again for all the help thus far!